# Sonata type collection - enable one input

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I'm using sonata_type_collection in my Sonata admin. I disable the input when my object is marked as processed. This disable all inputs in the line with process. Is it possible to enable one input of this line?

```
$formMapper->add(
    'processes',
    'sonata_type_collection',
    [
        'disabled' => $subject->isProcessed(),
    ],
    [
        ...
    ]
);
```

Example here:

[image: Example here]

Comment: could you show code of this template?

Comment: I didn't edit default Sonata template.